# How to obtain a lower-complexity version of OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, basemap, field-mapping, arcgis-field-maps

I would like to make a simple fieldwork map that displays sampling locations with respect to some specific highlighted areas (using polygons). I would like to do this on a relatively simple map that only shows the landmasses, coastal areas, rivers and other waterbodies, and cities (perhaps including some nuances in vegetation rover). In terms of style I really like the Öpnvkarte maps, as well as the OpenStreetMap basemap.

Though, on a normal satellite map, the sampling location names are must easier to read and the whole map feels much less chaotic, as seen in the comparison below.

[image]

Is there a way to alter the OpenStreetMaps or öpnvkarte specifically? Or could someone recommend a different basemap (or approach in general) that would work well here?

EDIT: Using a style editor like Maputnik might be the solution I was looking for! https://maputnik.github.io/editor/ Though I have no clue how to import such JSON file as a vector layer in QGIS.

[image]